# Adding second density plot undoes binning in first histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some issues adding a second density plot to an existing density + histogram ggplot. Namely, when I add the second density plot from another data source it changes the number of bins in the histogram of the first plot.

Here is the toy data/plot to illustrate my problem

```
# data
df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(1e4,0,1), var2=rnorm(1e4,5,1))

# create plot function
plotFunct <- function(data, varName, nBins) {
  p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x=varName)) + 
              geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), bins = nBins, fill = "white", colour = "black") +
              geom_density(fill = "#FF6666", alpha = .3)
  return(p)
}

# Now we run the function specifying 40 bins
p <- plotFunct(df, "var1", 40) 
p
```

[image]

So everything is working as it should be.

Next to create the second dataset to add to the first graph...

```
outsideData <- data.frame(outside = rnorm(1e5, -2, 25))
```

...and add it to the first plot. This data has a much wider spread so to make the graph more digestible we'll restrict it to a pre-specified range with the `coord_cartesian()` function

```
p2 <- p + geom_density(data = outsideData, aes(x=outside), colour = "green") + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5,5))

p2
```

[image]

The second density plot is in green. Note that a result of its addition is that the histogram in the first density plot has a single bin instead of the forty bins we specified originally. Somehow the addition of the second density plot has affected the binning of the first. However, the *density* portion of the original plot seems unaffected.

**Can anyone enlighten me how to revert back to the original histogram?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue why this is happening, but here is a possible bypass. It turns out that the behavior you describe does not occur when using `binwidth` instead of `bins`. So one approach is to pre-calculate a suitable bin width based on the desired number of bins:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)

# data
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(1e4, 0, 1), var2 = rnorm(1e4, 5, 1))

# create plot function
plotFunct <- function(data, varName, nBins) {
  vn <- as.name(varName)
  cuts <- pretty(data[,varName], nBins)
  binWidth <- abs(cuts[1]-cuts[2])
  cat("using ", nBins, "bins converted into binwidth", binWidth, "\n\n")
  p <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_histogram(
      aes(x = !!vn, y = ..density..),
      binwidth = binWidth,
      fill = "white",
      colour = "black"
    ) +
    geom_density(aes(x=!!vn), fill = "#FF6666", alpha = .3)
  return(p)
}

# Now we run the function specifying 40 bins
p <- plotFunct(df, "var1", 40)
p

outsideData <- data.frame(outside = rnorm(1e5,-2, 25))

p2 <-
  p + geom_density(
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    data = outsideData,
    aes(x = outside),
    colour = "green"
  ) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 5))

p2
```

Should make this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @teofil! Love the lazy eval in the function. Need to learn how to do that.